# Remove values in comma separated list from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table in my MySQL database called 'children'. In that table is a row called 'wishes' (a comma separated list of the child's wishlist items). I need to be able to update that list so that it only removes one value. i.e. the list = Size 12 regular jeans, Surfboard, Red Sox Baseball Cap; I want to remove Surfboard.

My query right now looks like this

```
$select = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM children WHERE caseNumber="'.$caseNum.'" LIMIT 1 ');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($select);

    foreach ($wish as $w) {
        $allWishes = $row['wishes'];
        $newWishes = str_replace($w, '', $allWishes);
        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE children SET wishes='$newWishes' WHERE caseNum='".$caseNum."'");
}
```

But the UPDATE query isn't removing anything. How can I do what I need?

Comment: I think wishes should be it's own table and linked back here by sharing the key caseNumber.

Comment: Looks to be missing 1 string concatenation but once that gets sorted you are leaving this query open to SQL Injection - a hacker would really get what they wished for.

Comment: @Daren - thats really the right answer, the DB model is wrong and needs fixing. Pity upvotes on comments dont count

Comment: I had wishes as it's own table, but it needs to be this way.

Comment: @sun-tzu Maybe you're already past this issue, but I added another possible solution to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [these user-defined `REGEXP_REPLACE()` functions](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp), you may be able to replace it with an empty string:

```
UPDATE children SET wishes = REGEXP_REPLACE(wishes, '(,(\s)?)?Surfboard', '') WHERE caseNum='whatever';
```

Unfortunately, you cannot just use plain old `REPLACE()` because you don't know where in the string 'Surfboard' appears.  In fact, the regex above would probably need additional tweaking if 'Surfboard' occurs at the beginning or end.

Perhaps you could trim off leading and trailing commas left over like this:

```
UPDATE children SET wishes = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(wishes, '(,(\s)?)?Surfboard', '')) WHERE caseNum='whatever';
```

So what's going on here?  The regex removes 'Surfboard' plus an optional comma & space before it.  Then the surrounding `TRIM()` function eliminates a possible leading comma in case 'Surfboard' occurred at the beginning of the string.  That could probably be handled by the regex as well, but frankly, I'm too tired to puzzle it out.

**Note,** I've never used these myself and cannot vouch for their effectiveness or robustness, but it is a place to start.  And, as others are mentioning in the comments, you really should have these in a normalized wishlist table, rather than as a comma-separated string.

**Update**

Thinking about this more, I'm more partial to just forcing the use of built-in `REPLACE()` and then cleaning out the extra comma where you may get two commas in a row.  This is looking for two commas side by side, as though there had been no spaces separating your original list items. If the items had been separated by commas and spaces, change `',,'` to `', ,'` in the outer `REPLACE()` call.

```
UPDATE children SET wishes = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(wishes, 'Surfboard', ''), ',,', ',')) WHERE caseNum='whatever';
```

Comment: I found this to be very close to what I need, however my values are not words, they are numbers:  IE:  `15,47,1154,315` - and when removing `1154` or `315` it worked, but when replacing `15`, it removed the 15 but also turned 1154 into `14` and 315 into `3`.  Its replacing every instance of `15`.  My statement is using `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('15',myColumn)`

Comment: @rolinger Then you need to adjust your regex to include word boundaries `\b` so it does not search in the middle of a set value. This is a good illustration of why storing comma-separated values in a column is problematic, stuffing 2D data into a 1D row (or 3D data into a 2D table)

Comment: true.  I am taking over project created by others.  Scratching my head on this one and quite a few other things as well.  Cheap short cuts without consideration of the future.  A quick fix for now, but noting this in the Master "TO FIX" list. I altered the query to the following:  `$query = "UPDATE myTable SET myColumn= TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', myColumn, ','), ',$pid,', ',')) where FIND_IN_SET('$pid',myColumn);"`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a direct answer to your question, but like Daren says it's be better having wishes as its own table. Maybe you could change your database schema so you have 3 tables, for instance:

```
children
-> caseNum
-> childName

wishes
-> caseNum
-> wishId
-> wishName

childrensWishes
-> caseNum
-> wishId
```

Then to add or delete a wish for a child, you just add or delete the relevant row from `childrensWishes`. Your current design makes it difficult to manipulate (as you're finding), plus leaves you at risk for inconsistent data.

As a more direct answer, you could fix your current way by getting the list of wishes, explode() 'ing them, removing the one you don't want from the array and implode() 'ing it back to a string to update the database.

Answer (score 0):

Make wishes table have this format:

```
caseNumber,wish
```

Then you get all of a child's wishes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM children c left join wishes w on c.caseNumber = w.caseNumber WHERE c.caseNumber= ?
```

Removing a wish becomes:

```
DELETE from wishes where caseNumber = ?
```

Adding a wish becomes:

```
INSERT into wishes (caseNumber,wish) values (?,?)
```

Returning one wish becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM children c left join wishes w on c.caseNumber = w.caseNumber WHERE c.caseNumber= ? LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the wishes indexed in an array which is thereafter serialized could be an idea, otherwise you would need to retrieve the string, slice it, remove the part you don't want, then concatenate the remains. This can be done by using the [**explode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

If you were to use an array, you would retrieve the array and then sort through it with a loop like this:

```
// Wishes array:
// Array (
//      [0] Regular Jeans
//      [1] Surfboard
//      [2] Red Sox Baseball Cap
// )

$wishes = $row['wishes']; // This is a serialized array taken from the database
$wishes = unserialize($wishes);

foreach ($wishes as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 'Surfboard') {
        unset($wishes[$key]);
        break;
    }
}

$wishes = serialize($wishes);
// Update database
```

Keep in mind that index [1] now won't exist in the array, so if you wish to have a clean array you should loop through the array and make it create a new array by itself:

```
foreach ($wishes as $wishes) {
    $newArray[] = $wishes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer to such issue is here 
[The best way to remove value from SET field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642658/the-best-way-to-remove-value-from-set-field)

query should be like this which covers the ,value or value, or only value in the comma separated column

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  categories =
    TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(CONCAT(',',REPLACE(col, ',', ',,'), ','),',2,', ''), ',,', ',')
    )
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET('2', categories)
```

Here you can have your condition in where clause. for more details refer above link.

Answer (score 0):

You can create function like this:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION `remove_from_set`(v int,lst longtext) RETURNS longtext CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
set @lst=REPLACE(@lst, ',,', ',');
set @lng=LENGTH(@lst) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@lst, ',', ''))+1;
set @p=find_in_set(@v,@lst);
set @l=SUBSTRING_INDEX( @lst, ',', @p-1);
set @r=SUBSTRING_INDEX( @lst, ',', @p-@lng);
IF @l!='' AND @r!='' THEN
    return CONCAT(@l,',',@r);
ELSE
    RETURN CONCAT(@l,'',@r);
END IF;
END
```

Using:

```
SELECT remove_from_set('1,,2,3,4,5,6',1)
```