# Delete a specific value from a string (string contains comma separated values)

Tags: mysql

For example, if I have a table structure like this:

```
Table 1
    ID Name Value

    001 Rajesh 90,100,210,400
    002 Suresh 100,400,300,66
    003 Mahesh 200,500
    004 Virat 400,578,57
```

How can I delete 400 from Suresh?

```
DELETE Value ="400" FROM table1
WHERE Name = 'Suresh'
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642658/the-best-way-to-remove-value-from-set-field Also see Docs: http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html To remove set elements from an existing set, we use the REPLACE function to remove the element. If using decimal values, we use a combination of the bitwise AND operator & with the bitwise NOT operator ~.

`UPDATE set_test SET myset = REPLACE(myset,'Dancing','')
      WHERE rowid = 6;
  UPDATE set_test SET myset = myset & ~2 WHERE rowid = 6;`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting the values into a second table which is related via the person's ID.  However, you can use the following query for your current situation:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Value = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', Value, ','), ',400,', ','))
WHERE Name = 'Suresh'
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d95fd/1).  For reference, see [MySQL's string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: is there any way we can change this in hql ?