# Remove values in comma separated list from database on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Edit :

I give another example,

products_table

```
| ID | product_name | images |
|---------------------------------------|
| 1 | Phone | img1.jpg,img2.jpg
| 2 | Canon | img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg
| 3 | Cocac | img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg,img4.jpg
| 4 | Lamps | img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg,img4.jpg
```

Lats say I remove image "img3.jpg" from Lamps product without remove other images. What is the SQL call to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to remove value from SET field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642658/the-best-way-to-remove-value-from-set-field)

Comment: Simple. DON'T have a comma separated list in an RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE products_table SET images=replace(images, 'img3.jpg,',''),images=replace(images, ',img3.jpg','') WHERE product_name='Lamps'");
```

Comment: code you given is working for delete but the last images can't delete.

Comment: @Googlemy I have updated my code. Hope now  this code delete  the last image. Thanks.