# REGEXP for not exist number in comma saperated string

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli

I have a table name tenders which contains the detail like:

```
+-------------------------------+
|  id     |    Sector           |
+-------------------------------+
|  1      |    1,3,5,9,7        |
+-------------------------------+
|  2      |    2,6,4,7,9,20     |
+-------------------------------+
|  3      |    1,2,3,55,47,52   |
+-------------------------------+
|  4      |    51,2,36,5,4,9,1  |
+-------------------------------+
```

I used the `REGEXP` to find the values using `mysql`

```
SELECT * FROM `tenders` WHERE sector REGEXP "[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]"
```

and to set `or` condition I use

```
SELECT * FROM `tenders` WHERE sector REGEXP "[[:<:]](1|2)[[:>:]]"
```

but I want to write a query where sector field neither exist `1` nor `2`. output should contain sector every other sector except `1` and `2`.

Comment: Do not store values as CSV. Learn about normalization

Comment: i know about normalization but the DB is remotely connected and cant have any changes on DB. I know i can get the record using mysql query but don't know the syntex. please help

Comment: So, for record 4, you want it to output ```51,36,5,4,9```?

Comment: yes @sloan thrasher you are right

Comment: You can do this easily in the PHP code after you run your query.

Comment: Edit your question and show the PHP code that calls the query.

Comment: I know i can do it using PHP. I want this output by query. Because after that i will have to filter the record. which i don't want to do. if there will not be any solution it will be the last way you are saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177851/discussion-between-harshwardhan-sharma-and-sloan-thrasher).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.

Actually it was so easy to get the output.

I just wrote the query like

```
SELECT * FROM `tenders` WHERE sector NOT REGEXP "[[:<:]](1|2)[[:>:]]"
```

and i got the output.

Comment: This doesn't actually match what you wrote in your answer to @SloanThrasher question 'So, for record 4, you want it to output 51,36,5,4,9". The other answers do attempt to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending your MySQL version, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` or `REGEXP`.
`TRIM` and `CONCAT` will do the trick (based on [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642658/the-best-way-to-remove-value-from-set-field/14643152#14643152) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798094/2144342)):

If your are using **MySQL >= 8.0** you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function:

```
SELECT id, 
TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(',',Sector,','),'(,1)|(,2)','')) 
FROM tenders;
```

For MySQL **Mysql < 8.0** you can use `REPLACE` function.

```
SELECT id, 
TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(',',Sector, ','),',2',''),',1','')) 
FROM tenders;
```

[You can see a working example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b3BdxekFSzQoT134SnE8bd/1)

Comment: This will replace e.g. 24 with 4 and will merge a number ending in 2 (e.g. 32) with the next number in the list.

Comment: You are right @Nick, I changed my Answer using REGEXP_REPLACE

Comment: @Nick I also added a working example using REPLACE function.

Comment: actually it not about only 1 and 2 there may be any number.And it seems very complex query.

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma I just simplified my answer. For MySQL 8 or above you can add more numbers in an easy way, but I agree it's a complex task with MySQL < 8. You should also think if its better to solve this problem creating a MySQL funciton, view or stored procedure and even if it's better to solve this problem using PHP instead of MySQL. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for regular expressions here, just wrap you `Sector` column with commas, so every number in a list is between commas, then you can easily check, if some number is there by looking for `,[number],` (ex. `,1,`) in concatenated column.

Here's query:

```
select id,
       Sector
from tbl
where locate(',1,', concat(',', Sector,',')) = 0 --1 is not in the list
  and locate(',2,', concat(',', Sector,',')) = 0 --and 2 is not in the list
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aZiNGGy2dexNwuYBdgMEHA/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(1, sector)
  AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(2, sector)
```

Performance:  for 2 items, it might be about the same as `NOT REGEXP`.  For more than 2 it is probably slower.  Techniques involving `CONCAT` will be slower.